# How to Save select option value data instead of Id using PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

How best can I save a select option value name instead of the id using just Ajax, PHP and MYSQL.
I tried many ways but for now when I select the data and store back it keeps saving generated id and that's not what I want.

When i decided to change the id of the selection option to value i the values does show on the drop down.

**Details.php**

```
  <form method="post" name="signup" onSubmit="return valid();">
                     <label class="control-label">Profile ID</label>
                     <select id="employee" name="regcode" class="form-control">
                     <option value="" selected="selected">Select Profile ID</option>
                       <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT id,regcode FROM tbstudentprofile";
                                  $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
                                  $query->execute();
                                  while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                                ?>
                                            <option name="regcode" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
                                                <?php echo $row["regcode"]; ?> </option>
                                                
                                            <?php }    ?>
                                        </select>
                                    <div class=" form-group1 form-last>
                                        <label class=" control-label">Status</label>
                                        <textarea name="status"  row="2"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                      <button type="submit"      name="save">Save </button>


</form>
enter code here
```

query

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $regcode = $_POST['regcode'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO studentschooltbl(regcode,status) VALUES(:regcode,:status)";

        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);    
        $query->bindParam(':regcode',  $regcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       
        $query->execute();
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
        if ($lastInsertId) {

            $msg = " Registration successfully";
        } else {
            $error = "error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: The value to each option would need to be the regcode value instead of the id. Personally, I prefer keeping id references, especially if related to look-up tables. This way you can easily join on the id reference, and if any regcode value ever changes, it's far more easily done in 1 place instead of updating across multiple rows/tables.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @PaulT., with the problem I already try using regcode instead of id and if that happens the values for the drop down doesn't show up and basically i wan to get the value name stored back into the database.

Comment: `<option value="<?php echo $row["regcode"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["regcode"]; ?></option>`  (I removed the name attribute, the select tag has this covered) ... should work, I see no reason what could cause that to `not show up`, unless a `regcode` contains some weird characters? When the page loads, right click on the page somewhere, click the `view page source` option to see what the rendered HTML looks like for the select.

Comment: @PaulT. that's really nice and working tho but there's a issue i'll have to address, I already an Ajax working when you select the particular drop with  it shows the  selected user name on the side if i use the **regcode** instead of  the **id**, it actually stops working, can you assist me on that.

Comment: Would need to update the question to include the ajax handling. It's likely a simple matter of not having the id now for the handling. (this goes back to keeping id references mentioned in my first comment ... seems that would it be easier to save the studentprofile id and status as a pair in the studentschool table instead of the regcode and status as a pair?) That's only my opinion though, I don't know the limits of your task.